# How to enter ^2x in Latex when using an integral statement

Tags: latex

I am new to learning Latex and I am trying to write an integral from 0 to infinity (e^2x)/(e^(3x)+7 however, everytime I try to enter my code snippet, it keeps giving me an undefined control sequence, which im pretty sure means I messed up somewhere when typing it out. Below is my code snippet that I am working with.

```
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^\2x}{e^3x+7}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand your question, but if I well understand, you should try this :

```
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}}{e^{3x+7}}dx
```

Comment: I think you mean `e^[3x}+7` in the denominator.  Also `\,` before `dx` is standard style.